# apt shows only an old version of the package

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, debian, apt

I am trying to install `ffmpeg` on my sistem, but for some reason when I do `sudo apt install ffmpeg` I only get the version `4.1.10-0+deb10u1`. This is an issue because one of my apps requires at least version `4.2.7`. When running `apt list --all-versions ffmpeg` I get the following output:

```bash
ffmpeg/oldstable,now 7:4.1.10-0+deb10u1 amd64 [installed]
ffmpeg/oldstable 7:4.1.9-0+deb10u1 amd64
```

I have run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` beforehand just in case, but it seems that the only options I have are those. I use `Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`, so I checked on their website and found that there is a stable version `4.3.5` available [here](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/ffmpeg). Maybe there Is something I need to update to see this version?

Comment: You're on old stable.  The current version in stable is 7:4.3.5-0+deb11u1.  Upgrade to stable?  It's usually painless.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that adding a new source fixes the issue.

You basically need to add these two lines in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```bash
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main
```

After that `apt list --all-versions ffmpeg` gave me the desired output:

```bash
ffmpeg/stable 7:4.3.5-0+deb11u1 amd64
ffmpeg/oldstable 7:4.1.10-0+deb10u1 amd64
ffmpeg/oldstable 7:4.1.9-0+deb10u1 amd64
```